# I updated my iPod touch (3g) to the iOS 4, but my hard drive filled up 1/2 way through

Tags: ipod-touch, ios

Part way through the iOS 4 update on my touch 3g my c: reached capacity. After clearing off some space I restarted iTunes. Now iTunes (and my touch) think that the latest version is installed. The touch still works fine, and it thinks it's running version 4, but it doesn't have any of the version 4 features! Is there anyway to force it to install version 4 again without doing a restore?

Answer (score 1):

Since yesterday there is the iOS 4.1 update. Maybe this can be installed without problems. Or, you should be able to reset the iPod (use the link "restore iPod" under "search for updates", maybe different words, I'm using German iTunes).

BTW: You didn't try to update your iPod Touch to *iPhone 4* but to *iOS 4* ;)

Answer (score 0):

Warning: I am not a qualified Apple support rep, so I'm not sure if the method prescribed here will work (i.e., caveat emptor), or put your phone in deeper trouble, but try this [link](http://www.iphonexpert.com/how-to-download-ios4-iphone-ipod-touch-gm-firmware-itunes-9-2-beta/), which has directions and links to the 4.0 "Gold Master" firmware.

Once you do this, if it works, when you update, also click on your iTunes iPod Touch "Summary Tab" button: "check for update" so you can then download and install iOS4.01 (which fixes a critical security vulnerability).

Comment: I'll give it a shot. I tried doing a restore but that put my touch in the same position it was in before the restore.

Answer (score 0):

Put it into DFU mode.

Try [this link](http://forum.pocketables.net/showthread.php?t=566) for more info.